# Build method is being called but list not getting updated

Tags: flutter, flutter-bloc

I have a build method inside a stateful widget which is being called but the List item is not getting updated. I have even tried providing a unique key but that didn't work out.
Though the widget gets updated when i scroll the list. The listitem is a separate stateful widget.

Answer (score 1):

Without a little piece of code we can't help properly.

One situation could be that you're defining the list inside build method, if you're using an Stateful Widget you should declare in State, then the changes would be correctly.